# Removing white layer which appears on floor after spilling water

Tags: flooring, floor

I'm pretty careless and sometimes spill a bit of water on our floor. When I do, some strange white layer appears on the floor within a minute. I took some photos to demo. Usually it gets much much worse, but I didn't want to leave the floor wet for long just to demonstrate.

[image: Floor]
[image: Spilled floor]
[image: Minute after spill]
[image: After removing spill]

If you leave something moist on the floor for an hour without noticing, it can be almost like someone drew on it with chalk. Attempts to scratch it off result in some weird grime peeling off, which I assume can't be good as it must be a part of the flooring.

What's the proper way to remove the layer after a spill?

Comment: Is that a wood floor? Perhaps it needs sealing with a waterproof coating?

Comment: We need details on just what that flooring is. I'm guessing it's some sort of wood laminate; is it?

Comment: I don't know what kind of flooring it is :/

Comment: [Can an iron + steam remove “heat stains” from a wood table?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/32719/can-an-iron-steam-remove-heat-stains-from-a-wood-table)

Comment: Looks to me like pre-finished hardwood. See the above link for suggestions on how to remove blemishes from wood.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is indeed laminate flooring.

**To take the stain out:**
Toothpaste lightly rubbed on the stain is often suggested. Another one  is vinegar mixed with a bit of olive oil.

**If the stain does not come out** - Using Tea to Mask White Stains on Laminate Flooring.

Take two tea bags, put in a cup, just about cover them with boiling water, leave it to cool, then put the liquid on the white marks on the laminate flooring. Just rub in gently with your fingers, leave for about half an hour, then remove some of the liquid with a tissue to check the result. The liquid (tea, which has tannin in - the colour agent) will have started to dry out. If the white mark is still evident leave for another 15 mins, then just wipe the area clean with a soft damp cloth. This worked for my laminate floor and it is now fully restored.